# Valor criado dentro da função está sendo apagado mesmo salvando o seu ponteiro em C++

Tags: c++, ponteiro

Estou criando uma LinkedList, onde cada elemento é uma `struct`, dessa forma:

```
template <typename Type> struct LinkedElement {
    Type content;
    LinkedElement<Type> *next = NULL;
};
```

Na minha classe `LinkedList`, dentro do método `add`, eu crio um novo `LinkedElement` para o elemento a ser adicionado à lista e salvo o seu ponteiro no atributo `next` do último elemento.

```
template <typename ElementType> class LinkedList {
    private:
        LinkedElement<ElementType> firstElement;
        int length = 0;

        struct LinkedElement<ElementType> createLinkedElement(ElementType element) {
            struct LinkedElement<ElementType> newElement;
            newElement.content = element;
            return newElement;
        }

    public:
        void add(ElementType element) {
            struct LinkedElement<ElementType> newElement = createLinkedElement(element);
            
            // Se não houver elemento, o elemento a ser adicionado será a cabeça da lista.
            if (length++ == 0) {
                firstElement = newElement;
                return;
            }

            // Percorre todos os elementos ligados até chegar ao último.
            struct LinkedElement<ElementType> lastElement = firstElement;

            while (lastElement.next != NULL) {
                lastElement = *lastElement.next;
            }

            // Insere no último elemento encontrado o ponteiro do novo elemento.
            lastElement.next = &newElement;
        }

        ElementType get(int index) {

            // Verifica se o índice é maior que o tamanho da lista.
            if (length - 1 < index) {
                throw std::out_of_range("list index out of range");
            }

            // Obtém o elemento no índice especificado.
            struct LinkedElement<ElementType> lastElement = firstElement;
            
            for (int i = 0; (i < index || lastElement.next != NULL); i++) {
                lastElement = *lastElement.next;
            }

            return lastElement.content;
        }
};
```

O problema é que o objeto não é salvo ao final da execução do método. Sempre que eu executo o `add`, o `next` do primeiro, e único até o momento, elemento da lista é sempre nulo. O que pode estar acontecendo?

Comment: Aqui `struct LinkedElement<ElementType> newElement = createLinkedElement(element);` essa estrutura `newElement` está sendo criada na Stack como uma cópia por valor da struct gerada por `createLinkedElement(element)` e aqui `firstElement = newElement;` possivelmente a propriedade `firstElement` recebe uma cópia por valor de `newElement` e por isso o valor de `firstElement` persiste após o fim da função.

Comment: Já aqui `lastElement.next = &newElement;` o campo `firstElement.next`(lembre-se que `firstElement` persiste) recebe um ponteiro para `newElement` que foi alocado no stack e tudo que é alocado no stack é descartado após o término da função. Fiz esse [exemplo](https://ideone.com/BjKtXe) baseado no código da pergunta fazendo passagens de ponteiros e alocando cada nova estrutura `LinkedElement()` no Heap.

Comment: Sei que esse fragmento faz parte de um código maior de um modelo de classe, mas se trouxer mais elementos como uma declaração simplificada da classe `LinkedList` da propriedade `firstElement` e a declaração do método que encapsula o fragmento mostrado na pergunta(um caso de testes seria bom), me sentiria mais à vontade para escrever uma resposta detalhando o que está ocorrendo com esse fragmento. De uma olhada em [O que são e onde estão a "stack" e "heap"?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3797/o-que-s%C3%A3o-e-onde-est%C3%A3o-a-stack-e-heap)

Comment: @AugustoVasques Coloquei o código completo.

Comment: De fato, o problema principal era que ao fazer `lastElement = firstElement` e `lastElement.next = &newElement`, eu pegava a cópia do valor como você disse, Eu meio que pensei que, por `firstElement` ser atributo de classe, de alguma forma eu conseguiria alterar o objeto diretamente, pelo `lastElement` (estou me acostumando ainda com C++ rsrs).

Comment: Um outro problema também, depois de ter solucionado o problema principal, era no retorno do `createLinkedElement`. Eu resolvi imprimir o endereço de memória do retorno, e curiosamente dava sempre o mesmo. Pesquisando na internet, em um blog qualquer, eu descobri que o endereço de memória de qualquer objeto local é sempre o mesmo. Ou seja, mesmo que eu chame uma função foo() infinitas vezes, o retorno dela, mesmo que seja um objeto diferente, vai ser um objeto numa mesma posição de memória das outras chamadas. Isso é verdade? Por que o endereço não muda?

Comment: Aqui https://ideone.com/qfa842 dei uma revisada no seu código tinha muito conceito de C que removi. Verificando nesse [outro sandbox](https://ideone.com/Jogn3n) vi que o código da pergunta depois da edição não apresenta mais o erro que iniciou a pergunta e também não contém o mesmo [código original](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/revisions/550476/1) da pergunta. Eu não sei o que fazer....

Comment: *...eu descobri que o endereço de memória de qualquer objeto local é sempre o mesmo...* está explicado no link que passei [O que são e onde estão a "stack" e "heap"?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3797/o-que-s%C3%A3o-e-onde-est%C3%A3o-a-stack-e-heap)

Comment: @AugustoVasques Eu tinha colocado sem querer o código solução. Editei a pergunta e vou ler esse link. Obrigado!

Comment: poste um código completo, compilável. É natural que `add()` sempre crie um novo elemento então não há razão para existir `createLinkedElement()`. Nunca adicione um valor recebido como argumento na sua lista porque pode ser um temporário e deixar de existir: crie um novo node e copie o valor recebido. Não use templates antes de testar o código. Não acrescenta nada e só vai atrapalhar os testes e te fazer digitar muito mais.

Comment: Um método`get(n)` não tem muito sentido em uma lista ligada. Quando isso é importante se usa um array

Comment: Uma coisa a considerar: muito embora se vá declarar LinkedList<Type> e do ponto de vista de uso seja mesmo assim, do ponto de vista de implementação a lista não é de `ElementType` ou `Type`, mas sim de nodes. Os nodes é que são alvo da template e assim seria mais simples descrever as classes como tal e usar 3 classes. A lista ligada é de nodes e os nodes tem um conteúdo que é o alvo da template e um ponteiro para outro node.

Comment: Onde está o código completo?